# git add <path>/ (with trailing slash) -> why this is a bad practice?

Tags: git

What's the difference in the following commands?

```
%> git add <path>
```

and

```
%> git add <path>/
```

I mean what does the trailing slash `'/'` actually do?

Why it's not recommended to use it?

Thank you!

Comment: `git add` alone does nothing. `/` in bash refers to the system root. To add everything in a repo, open the root directory *of the repo* and do a `git add .` Check the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).

Comment: Where is the claim that this is a bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

In the bad old days, if you had a submodule whose path was `path/to/submodule` and you ran:

```
git add path/to/submodule/
```

Git would add the *entire contents* of `path/to/submodule/` (i.e., every file in it, recursively) to the index, rather than updating the submodule's gitlink.  Does it still do this?  I have not been brave enough to try it.

Other than this, there's no particular reason to avoid `git add path/`.  But to those of us who got burned, that's like saying "other than that time we all caught fire and suffered horribly, there's no reason to be cautious about fires".  We're probably still going to be very cautious with fire. :-)